# Accessing Keyframes when adding via low-level method

Tags: keyframes, fcurves, actions

If there are a lot of keyframes and a script continues to add keyframes, the script will get slower and slower as the animation grows. Supposedly this can be solved using more low-level methods, but it seems to depend on making a new action, and storing a new set of fcurves to a variable in order to access it. If I run such a script, but then want a script to edit that animation at some future time, but that variable does not already exist in the script that is currently running, how on Earth would I ever gain access to those f-Curves?
examples of "obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.find('MyAction')" don't get me anywhere. For context, this started out when I found this example below:

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.animation_data_create()
obj.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new(name="MyAction")
fcu_z = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path="location", index=2)
#   ??? If later I run another script that did not set up fcu_z in this way, I have no way to access it
fcu_z.keyframe_points.add(2)
fcu_z.keyframe_points[0].co = 10.0, 0.0
fcu_z.keyframe_points[1].co = 20.0, 1.0
```

Comment: You can search for an existing fcurve that affects the Z Location, `[fcu for fcu in action.fcurves if fcu.data_path == "location" and fcu.array_index == 2]`. Create one if not found.

Comment: @scurest It looks like this may work. Thank you very much.